# Nvidia linux drivers on Dell XPS L502X Nvidia GeForce GT 540M

Tags: linux, linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

I have a Dell XPS L502X with an Nvidia GeForce GT 540M and I'd like help installing the official drivers off the Nvidia site. Every time I try I brick my installation and have to re-install. Even if I restore my Xorg.conf it still has some serious bugs. I'm currently running the drivers from inside the driver manager but I want to use the latest ones on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well because of nVidia Optimus, you cannot directly install the nVidia drivers off the nVidia site. This is cause your laptop dynamically switches from the Intel Video Card to the nVidia Card as and when needed.
You will have to install Bumblebee or IronHide, I use Bumblebee and have no problems with it and recommend that.
To install Bumblebee follow the steps below [which I got from here](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1687), the order is important.

- From Package Manager:

  1. install bumblebee with bbswitch-dkms
  2. install primus
  3. install bumblebee-nvidia  (the Manager will add a few dependencies - accept these as well)
- From Driver Manager (accessible through Control Centre)

  1. install recommended Nvidia driver

Comment: I have bumblebee and primus and those drivers...I know how to set it up I just wanted to use the latest drivers.

Comment: I have not used Mint, but from my experience, they eventually give you the new driver

Comment: alright :/...is there no way to use the driver on the site.

Comment: sorry not that i know of, I have the same laptop. I wait for a community release.